# Overwriting Javascript cookie with data from another cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

This seems like a fairly simple question... I am trying to overwrite the data from cookie `a` with the data that is stored in cookie `b` but without changing either of the names of the cookies. Cookie `b` contains the particular user's defaults while cookie `a` stores the users current selections.

I have looked online and taken a few shots in the dark but, I have no leads! Everything that I've tried overwrites the entire cookie and I only want the data in cookie `a` to be changed, with no changes to the names of the cookies or to the data of any other cookies

Is this possible? If so how can I accomplish this task?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I’d like to know what you have tried and how you managed to overwrite the cookie’s name…

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question (although I'm working on an answer), but why don't you just store the current selections in a javascript variable instead of putting it into a cookie? That sounds like some extra work for no reason to save temporary selections to a cookie

Comment: What do you mean "altering the name"? If you're saving a cookie under a different name then you're not overwriting it. What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you add your attempts?

Comment: How about you make an AJAX request and do it server side ?

Comment: @DavidYue you're joking, right? Why would we do that when we can avoid the server altogether and do it on the client side, making it use less languages and also faster?

Comment: What did you try that did not work?

Comment: Show. Your. Code. Then, show what you expect, and what you are actually getting.

Comment: Apologies!  I'm quite new to Javascript and programming in general and I've recently joined in on a pre-existing project.  @Markasoftware: Cookie 'a' is created (and used) by several of pieces of code so I have take it as is.  I've double checked and yes, Jan, you are absolutely correct, I don't think I am actually overwriting the cookie name! Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code. It's commented enough to answer the question:

```
//first, get the "b" cookie's value
var cooks=document.cookie;
//just the "b" part of the cookie string
var bStartIndex=cooks.indexOf('b=')+2; //get the start of the b part of the string
var bEndIndex=cooks.indexOf(';',bStartIndex); //and the end of it
//and then extract the actual variable value from it
var b=cooks.slice(bStartIndex,bEndIndex!==-1?bEndIndex:null); //in case b was the last var, there would be no ; after it, so bEndIndex would be -1
//now, we set a to that
document.cookie='a='+b; //I don't THINK this will overwrite other cookies
```

I haven't tested it, but it SHOULD work. Tell me if it doesn't and I'll try to fix it

There are probably libraries out there that could make this a lot easier, if you're planning to use this in production

Comment: Thank you Markasoftware.  I will try this now and get back to you

Comment: Thank you Markasoftware! The answer you provided guided me to what I needed. I had to remove the bEndIndex section and the !==-1?bEndIndex:null section because I am calling this with a function and the first time I would call the function it would clear the contents of the cookie rather than put the data into it.  Apologies for the slow answer reward, stack exchange has not been functioning properly for me since I asked this question